# Help configuring the log4cplus configuration file (properties file)

Tags: c++, logging, log4j, log4cplus

I created a new Logger object like this:

```
log4cplus::Logger m_WebAccessLogger;  //a class member
```

Then in the constructor initialization list I do:

```
m_WebAccessLogger(log4cplus::Logger::getInstance("WebAccess")
```

This works fine, it logs as expected.  What I'm having trouble with is, I want to configure the log4cplus.properties file so that everything for "WebAccess" will go to a separate log file (right now it goes to the default log file where everything else goes).

I can't seem to find the documentation for how to configure these properties files, so I need help please!

Here's my current log properties, how can I tell it to have "WebAccess" go to a different file?

```
log4cplus.rootLogger=DEBUG, ROLLING
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT=log4cplus::ConsoleAppender
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c{2} %%%x%% - %m [%l]%n
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%H:%M:%S} [%t] - %m%n

log4cplus.appender.ROLLING=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.MaxBackupIndex=5
#log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c{2} %%%x%% - %m [%l]%n
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.layout=log4cplus::TTCCLayout
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.File=c:\projects\ArchiveService\IArchive.log
```

Something like: 
WebAccess.File=c:\projects\ArchiveService\webaccess.log 
or 
log4cplus.WebAccess.File=webaccess.log

I know log4cplus is simular to log4j, that why I put that as a Tag for this one.

Comment: How are you able to compile this line?
`m_WebAccessLogger(log4cplus::Logger::getInstance("WebAccess"))` ? Log4cplus doesn't provide any such method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out by guessing.

```
log4cplus.rootLogger=DEBUG, ROLLING
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT=log4cplus::ConsoleAppender
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c{2} %%%x%% - %m [%l]%n
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%H:%M:%S} [%t] - %m%n

log4cplus.appender.ROLLING=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.MaxBackupIndex=5
#log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c{2} %%%x%% - %m [%l]%n
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.layout=log4cplus::TTCCLayout
log4cplus.appender.ROLLING.File=c:\projects\ArchiveService\Debug\ImageArchive.log

log4cplus.logger.WebAccess=DEBUG, R2
log4cplus.appender.R2=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.R2.File=c:\projects\ArchiveService\Debug\webaccess.log
log4cplus.appender.R2.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4cplus.appender.R2.MaxBackupIndex=5
#log4cplus.appender.R2.layout=log4cplus::TTCCLayout
```

Comment: Sad this seems to be the only way to figure out the log properties file!

Answer (score 2):

*Original question was answered 2010. Log4cplus documentation for configuration is still a little hard to find... For anyone browsing through here:*

---

Here is a detailed example for log4cplus configuration files:

http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PropertyConfigurator.html#a21e8e6b1440cc7a8a47b8fd14c54b239

Comment: Thanks for the link - recommended reading for all working with log4cplus!